# Error with copy module using ansible 2.1

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I was able to use the ansible 2.1 copy module when I had the roles directory inside my parent ansible directory.  I then proceeded to move the roles directory inside my playbooks directory (since I was getting an error complaining about missing roles when calling plays inside the playbook directory and keeping the roles inside the main ansible directory).  Now, when I run the same tasks, the copy command appears to fail with the error copied below (nothing has changed on the remote machine).

**task**

```
- copy: src={{ debian_build.stdout }}  dest=/home/ubuntu/ owner=ubuntu group=ubuntu mode=644 backup=yes
  become: true
  become_user: root 
  become_method: sudo
```

debian_build is a valid path.

**error**

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/home/ubuntu/test-server_0.1.0-27686387a8b765f3dfb0bfea287737f97f223f14_all.deb): MODULE FAILURE"}
```

**Updated**

**site.yml**

```
## move artifacts to remote servers
- include: playbooks/test.yml
```

**playbooks/test.yml**

```
---
- name:  test deployment for xyz 
  hosts: testservers
  strategy: debug  ## turn off if not debugging

  roles:
  - test
```

**test/tasks**

### **main.yml**

- include: copy.yml

**copy.yml**

I tried modifying the copy.yml to the following as well but neither works.

```
---
- name: transferring artifact to server
  copy:
    src: "{{ lookup('fileglob','/tmp/test/testproj/target/*.deb', wantlist=true) | first }}"
    dest: /home/ubuntu/
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
    mode: 644
    backup: yes
  become: true
  become_user: root 
  become_method: sudo

#  local_action: shell ls -d /tmp/repos/latchapi-beta/target/*.deb
#  register: debian_build
#- debug: msg={{ debian_build.stdout }}

#- copy: src={{ debian_build.stdout }}  dest=/home/ubuntu/ owner=ubuntu group=ubuntu mode=644 backup=yes
#  become: true
#  become_user: root
#  become_method: sudo
```

When I run the playbook with -vvv, I get the following output before the error message:

```
ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ForwardAgent=yes -o Port=1212 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> PUT /tmp/tmpRHKTU1 TO /home/testuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420/stat
<ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ForwardAgent=yes -o Port=1212 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 '[ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com]'
<ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ForwardAgent=yes -o Port=1212 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -tt ec2-abc.def.ghi.jkl.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-khhahbdoujszvmnsqqqoglhkeeihbcog; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/testuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420/stat; rm -rf "/home/testuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476129233.91-106561207229420/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Comment: Can you please provide your playbook file?

Comment: @Avalon just updated - thanks a million

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the issue is with this one. Based on the error I'd assume the file doesn't exist. I'll let someone else answer.

Comment: @Avalon - I ended up install acl tools - it worked after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed acl tools and my ansible playbook worked after that:

```
- name: install setfacl support
  become: yes
  apt: pkg=acl
```